# jms onMessage() halt operations until signalled to consume

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I was looking for a functionality to stall the consumption of jms messages until a button click from ui. I use activemq for jms broker. And spring to create jms:listeners with a queue declared. However, the requirement is to stall the consumption of messages in onMessage() part of the MessageListener.

I have used receiveTimeout , after I changed the jms:listener in spring to defaultMessageListener as spring bean. 
Kindly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Believe you just need to control the listener and be able to stop/start programmatically, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11407838/start-and-stop-jms-listener-using-spring).

Comment: the stop() functionality does not work properly. I tried a shutdown() , and it is not possible to restart once I do a shutdown.   The stop() has the following code-   synchronized (this.lifecycleMonitor) {
   this.running = false;
   this.lifecycleMonitor.notifyAll();
  }  which does not really affect the executeOngoingLoop() . Please suggest as it is in syncronized block. I am refering to DefaultMessageListenerContainer in spring.